# How can I create a HashSet from a borrowed array of a generic type in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a function taking two borrowed arrays of a generic type `T`, and I would like to create `HashSet`s from those arrays so I can compare them.

I thought I would be able to do something like this:

```
pub fn sublist<T: PartialEq>(first_list: &[T], second_list: &[T]) -> bool {
  let first_set: HashSet<T> = first_list.iter().collect();
  let second_set: HashSet<T> = second_list.iter().collect();

  first_set.is_subset(&second_set)
}
```

But I end up with the following errors:

```
a value of type `std::collections::HashSet<T>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&T`

value of type `std::collections::HashSet<T>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&T>`

help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&T>` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashSet<T>`
```

Because of the first line in the error, I thought I might be able to solve it like this (I just changed the hashset type to references `&T`):

```
pub fn sublist<T: PartialEq>(first_list: &[T], second_list: &[T]) -> bool {
  let first_set: HashSet<&T> = first_list.iter().collect();
  let second_set: HashSet<&T> = second_list.iter().collect();

  first_set.is_subset(&second_set)
}
```

But then I see these errors:

```
the trait bound `T: std::cmp::Eq` is not satisfied

the trait `std::cmp::Eq` is not implemented for `T`

note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::Eq` for `&T`
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::FromIterator<&T>` for `std::collections::HashSet<&T>`
```

I don't understand how to create new data structures from references to an array. Is it the fact that these arrays are borrowed that is the problem, or is it ultimately the trait bound on `PartialEq` that is the problem?

What if, for whatever reason, I can't modify the function signature, how can I use hashsets to compare the collections?

Comment: `HashSet` requires `Eq`, `PartialEq` is not enough. You're also probably going to have an error about missing the trait bound `Hash` as well if you haven't already.

Comment: Meaning it's impossible to use `HashSet` to compare these arrays? Would it be idiomatic to do the comparison manually then or is there some other collection I should be using?

Comment: Rust requires any functionality of generics to be declared up front. If `PartialEq` is all you have to work with, then you can't use any kind of hashed or ordered container to make the check efficient. You could put them in a `Vec` but if you can't even sort them (requires `Ord`) then why bother? Using [`.contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.slice.html#method.contains) directly in a loop is really the only option I see with the given constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `HashSet` your function needs to have the `Eq` and `Hash` trait bounds:

```
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn sublist<T: Eq + Hash>(first_list: &[T], second_list: &[T]) -> bool {
  let first_set: HashSet<&T> = first_list.iter().collect();
  let second_set: HashSet<&T> = second_list.iter().collect();

  first_set.is_subset(&second_set)
}
```

If you only know that `T` is `PartialEq`, then you can implement it like so:

```rust
pub fn sublist<T: PartialEq>(first_list: &[T], second_list: &[T]) -> bool {
    first_list.iter().all(|v| second_list.contains(v))
}
```

Other options include `T: Ord` and use `BTreeSet`.